# Tensorflow Object Detection API Out of Memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am new to tensorflow and trying to train my own object detection model.

Hardware: have tried multiple things, but biggest was a 32gb cpu. Also tried a 8gb cpu & 2gb gpu.

All running windows, python 3.6.2 & tensorflow 1.3

I've been following the guide here https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

Error is: (sorry, VM was shut down and that's all I have)
[error message OOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhNaI.png)

Batch Size: 3

Im starting to think my issue is the initial image size (4mb, 4288x3216), so I've been trying other resources (paperspace) and am still running out of memory on an 8gb gpu.

Ive got 571 images to train the model, and and 250 or so more for testing, all of the same size.

Any suggestions on passing the model a smaller amount of data so that I can keep it running?

As one of the comments suggested, I can resize but how will that affect my XML file?

Comment: Are you saying the image you are passing in is 4288x3216? If so, that will definitely eat up a ton of memory. Try cropping your images down heavily as well as reducing your batch size. Batch size should almost always be the first thing to lower when you are running OOM.

Comment: These models are trained on a 600x600 image. You should resize your input image to that size. Also try a batch size of 1 as above suggested.

Comment: @KentSommer - yes, that's the size of the image i'm passing. I was able to get to about 9 steps when running off a 32gb cpu